# how to have one urls for each language in django

Tags: python, django, url

I have these urls. And all three show the same contents. But with the text translated into their language.
How to manage the urls in dajngo for each language?

1: https://example.com/es/cursos

2: https://example.com/en/courses

3: https://example.com/de/schulungen

the url must change according to the language that is selected. It is the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely head on over to the Django docs on this sort of thing as they have a great example on how to handle it:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.urls import include, path
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


news_patterns = ([
    path('', news_views.index, name='index'),
    path(_('category/<slug:slug>/'), news_views.category, name='category'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', news_views.details, name='detail'),
], 'news')

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(_('about/'), about_views.main, name='about'),
    path(_('news/'), include(news_patterns, namespace='news')),
)

# If english
# '/en/news/category/recent/'

# If netherlands
# '/nl/nieuws/categorie/recent/'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns